# Locate specific image over multiple pages with Jquery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

Is there a way to search through several pages on a website to detect which one contains a particular image, using some sort of Jquery/AJAX combination?

I have a website that is continually updated, so content is pushed down across multiple pages, and might be on page but will move to another over time. I want to be able to handle links to specific images (I use Jquery to add a hash for each one), even if they're no longer on a specific page.

My link structure:

```
http://example.com/2/#img-123
```

Where '2' is the current page number and '#img-123' identifies the specific image. That same image, after a few weeks, may move from page 2 to 3, for instance.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I am trying to use a while loop to add content until the image is on the page, essentially (I have an infinite loading system essentially, so can just keeping add through my sequential pages, until I reach the right one).

I'm having problems with this code:

```
while (element.length == 0) {
   // BLOCK OF CODE
}
```

It doesn't seem to be correctly firing, whilst an if statement with the same condition does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes, there are a way to achive this. what did you tried so far?

Comment: Do expect users to have the page open for a really, really long time, without refreshing nor navigating away?

Comment: What I mean is that a user might share/link to http://example.com/2/#img-123. After some time however, this link will eventually break because img-123 will be moved from page 2 to page 3.

I've not yet tried anything specific. I assume there is an AJAX way of searching through my index pages looking for the correct image and then navigating to that page?

Comment: Try something, think of how this could be done, (redirect after not finding the image with javascript, or change the link structure, ...) and come back if you actually get stuck when coding something

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to add anther page to the app that displays a specific image (and whatever else you need shown - perhaps it could even work out what page the image would be on, and redirect to that, though that loses the permanent link) - such as 'example.com/img/123' - then you can offer that up as the permanent link for the image.

Having client side JavaScript code downloading and scanning through multiple page contents do not sound like a good idea.

Another alternative might be to use a web service to get the server to tell you what the url is for a specific image, but this wouldn't give a bookmark-able permanent link.